# Why does my 1803 Windows 10 says "You're up to date"?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1809

I discovered I have not installed the latest 1809 update on my `Windows Education` that I run at home. When I fetch for updates I can only see:

> You're up to date

But, I know I am missing the 1809 update. How should I install it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But, I know I am missing the 1809 update. How should I install it?

You currently cannot because Microsoft has retracted the update as people complained about their My Documents being removed if they didn't have the latest version of OneDrive.

So how to install, wait until Microsoft releases the update again, then you can install it. So technically speaking, yes, you are indeed up-to-date.

*Posted this answer because the other answer, although correct felt incomplete to me.*

Comment: if the other answer felt incomplete, well you know there's an edit button

Comment: @Magnetic_dud sorry, but that's not what the edit button is for. Many of us would find it really bad to edit someone else's answer to change its content. The edit button is there mostly to make it more readable or altering grammar, not to change the actual meaning, unless you change your post as a wiki.

Answer (score 3):

Because Microsoft temporarily removed the 1809 update from Windows Update, due to the "deletes user files" bug that could happen on some PCs

edit: as of 13 november, the update has been re-released, you can get it now: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4464619/windows-10-update-history (rollout will happen in the next days, it might not be immediately available for your device)

Comment: This answer could be improved by linking to a reference.